# Reading file data without size limitation

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file-io, char

In the following example of file reading from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_files_streams.htm):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
   char data[100];

   // open a file in write mode.
   ofstream outfile;
   outfile.open("afile.dat");

   cout << "Writing to the file" << endl;
   cout << "Enter your name: "; 
   cin.getline(data, 100);

   // write inputted data into the file.
   outfile << data << endl;

   cout << "Enter your age: "; 
   cin >> data;
   cin.ignore();

   // again write inputted data into the file.
   outfile << data << endl;

   // close the opened file.
   outfile.close();

   // open a file in read mode.
   ifstream infile; 
   infile.open("afile.dat"); 

   cout << "Reading from the file" << endl; 
   infile >> data; 

   // write the data at the screen.
   cout << data << endl;

   // again read the data from the file and display it.
   infile >> data; 
   cout << data << endl; 

   // close the opened file.
   infile.close();

   return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

1. The `data` variable is of length 100. What will happen if user enters data longer than 100 or if the file used to read into data has length > 100?
2. What can we use so that there is no limitation of size for data?
3. Can we use `string data` rather than `char data[100]` here?

I did not try these out since these involve file operations and major errors can cause disk data damage.

Comment: 1. [Well documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline). `getline` reads what it can and forces you to deal with the problem by entering a fail state and refusing to read any more until the error is `clear`ed. 2. use  
 [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) 3. yes, but you have to use `std::getline` instead of `std::istream::getline`

Comment: Apologies. I missed the later `infile >> data;`. This just plain <expletive deleted>s up because it does not know about the 100 character limit. This will wander into undefined behaviour running off the end of `data`. Solution is use `std::string` again.

Comment: If you need to work with an indeterminate and very large data set that is larger than the available memory you have, you'll need to work with it in chunks. Read a portion, process/display it, free it, then move on to the next portion, and keep on doing that until you've reached the end.

Comment: That clarifies a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. The `data` variable is of length 100. What will happen if user enters data longer than 100 or if the file used to read into data has length > 100?

The behaviour of the program will be undefined.

> 2. What can we use so that there is no limitation of size for data?

`std::string`. It's size is limited only by the size of virtual address space, as well as avaialable memory.

> 3. Can we use `string data` rather than `char data[100]` here?

Assuming `string` is `std::string`, then yes.

Comment: So I can just do: `string data; infile >> data` ?